# C copy 3-dimensional array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memory, copy

I have a pointer to a 3-dimensional array, like this:

```
char ***_cube3d
```

And I am initialising it like this:

```
_cube3d = (char ***)malloc(size * (sizeof(char**)));
for (int i = 0; i< size; i++) {
    _cube3d[i] = (char **)malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
    for (int j = 0; j<size; j++) {
        _cube3d[i][j] = (char *)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

Note that the array is of dynamic size, and can contain thousands of elements, so we cannot declare it as an array in advance.

Now, I want to copy all of its contents into another array, as efficiently as possible. I know the nested loop solution where we copy each element one by one, however, it seems extremely inefficient to me. Is there a way to speed this process up? C++ code is welcome, although I would prefer it in plain C, since I am planning to iterate this solution into Objective C, and I would like to avoid injecting C++ code into a clean Objective C project.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Make a single, contiguous array and access it in strides. Then it's trivial to copy.

Comment: Your first two mallocs need to be bigger. you want side * sizeof(char *), not side.

Comment: I think the fastest copy will be as @KerrekSB suggests. It will result in basically zero cache misses. However, a single contiguous allocation could potentially be quite large, so it might be better to leave it as you have it now. TBH, I don't think there will be much of a performance difference as long as you copy in stride.

Comment: Efficient copy code *for this data structure* would be to allocate the copy using the code above (fixed as Charlie indicates), and do a `memcpy` of each of the innermost allocations. Saves copying elements one by one. As KerrekSB says, a different data structure can be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using C.99, you can use a variable length array (VLA) to dynamically allocate your 3-dimensional array.  Once `side` is determined, you can declare your pointer to be:

```
char (*cube3d_)[side][side];
```

And then initialize it like this:

```
cube3d_ = malloc(side * sizeof(*cube3d_));
```

Note that in C, you are not required to cast the return value of `malloc()`, and doing so can actually lead to undefined behavior in the worst case. Since the "cube" has been allocated as a contiguous block, it can be copied with `memcpy()`.

C++ does not have VLA. You can use a `vector` to get the C++ equivalent of your multi-dynamic allocation structure:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<char> > >
cube3d_(side, std::vector<std::vector<char> >(side, std::vector<char>(side)));
```

You can then copy it using a copy constructor or an assignment.

---

If `cube3d_` is a member variable of an object/structure, so long as your object knows the value of `side`, you can still use a VLA pointer to access the memory.  For example:

```
struct Obj {
    size_t side_;
    void *cube3d_;
};

//...
size_t side = 3;

//...
Obj o;
o.side_ = side;
char (*p)[o.side_][o.side_] = malloc(o.side_ * sizeof(*p));
o.cube3d_ = p;

//...
char (*q)[o.side_][o.side_] = o.cube3d_;
q[1][2][2] = 'a';
```

Comment: The 'char (*cube3d_)[side][side];' has to be inside a function where 'size' is defined, right? So the type "cube3d_" has a lifetime within that function. I don't see how this is easily passed down to other functions. If you return the malloc'ed cube3d_ the calling party doesn't have the type. Am I confused or missing something? Thanks.

Comment: @CharlieBurns: If you want a function to allocate the array for you, you can pass in a pointer to the pointer for that purpose: `int allocate_3d (size_t side, char (**p)[side][side]) {...}`.

Comment: Yes, but 'side' still needs to be known since you are passing a pointer to a pointer with having its size defined, right? Thanks for your comment. However, I cannot afford to have the size known in advance. This char*** is an instance variable, and the object is initialised with the size as the parameter, so there is no way to know anything about the size of the array in advance.

Comment: @csotiriou: Please see my updated answer on how you can use VLA with an instance variable.

Comment: Your solution is elegant in order to initialise and copy. I will accept this as the answer, since it works and taught me something I don't know, but I may end up implementing it into a plain array, like Richard Chambers indicated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using what you already have (but fixing the first `malloc` with `sizeof(char***)`)

You could copy the array by running a bunch of for loops like this:

```
char new_cube[side][side][side];
for(unsigned int x = 0; x < side; x++)
    for(unsigned int y = 0; y < side; y++)
        for(unsigned int z = 0; z < side; z++)
            new_cube[x][y][z] = old_cube[x][y][z];
```

OR:

```
char new_cube[side][side][side];
for(unsigned int x = 0; x < side; x++)
    for(unsigned int y = 0; y < side; y++)
        memcpy(new_cude[x][y], old_cube[x][y], sizeof(char)*side);
```

which might be a bit faster.

using this method you avoid using any c++(as you said you would like) and your code complexity is kept minimal.

Comment: +1 for the fix. I will edit my answer. Thanks. That is a bit faster for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using C and structs to provide some degree of object oriented along with a set of helper functions.

The idea here was to use Kerrick's suggestion of a contiguous array.

I am not sure if I got the offset calculation correct and it has not been tested so it is worth what you are paying for it.  However it may be helpful as a starting place.

The idea is to have a single contiguous area of memory to make memory management easier.  And to use a function to access a particular element using a zero based offset in the x, y, and z directions.  And since I was not sure as to the element size/type, I made that a variable as well.

```
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct _Array3d {
    int   elSize;     // size of each element of the array in bytes
    int   side;       // length of each side of the 3d cube in elements
    char  * (*Access) (struct _Array3d *pObj, int x, int y, int z);
    char  buffer[1];
} Array3d;

static  char * Array3d_Access (Array3d *pObj, int x, int y, int z)
{
    char *pBuf = NULL;

    if (pObj && x < pObj->side && y < pObj->side && z < pObj->side) {
        pBuf = &(pObj->buffer[x * pObj->side * pObj->elSize * pObj->side * pObj->elSize + y * pObj->side * pObj->elSize + z * pObj->elSize]);
    }

    return pBuf;
}

// Create an Array3d cube by specifying the length of each side along with the size of each element.
Array3d *Array3d_Factory (int side, int elSize)
{
    Array3d *pBuffer = malloc (sizeof(Array3d) + side * elSize * side * elSize * side * elSize);

    if (pBuffer) {
        pBuffer->elSize = elSize;
        pBuffer->side = side;
        pBuffer->Access = Array3d_Access;
    }

    return pBuffer;
}

// Create an Array3d cube that is the same size as an existing Array3d cube.
Array3d *Array3d_FactoryObj (Array3d *pObj)
{
    Array3d *pBuffer = NULL;

    if (pObj) {
        int     iBufferSize = pObj->side * pObj->elSize * pObj->side * pObj->elSize * pObj->side * pObj->elSize;

        pBuffer = malloc (sizeof(Array3d) + iBufferSize);
        if (pBuffer) {
            pBuffer->elSize = pObj->elSize;
            pBuffer->side = pObj->side;
            pBuffer->Access = pObj->Access;
        }
    }

    return pBuffer;
}

// Duplicate or clone an existing Array3d cube into new one.
// Returns NULL if cloning did not happen.
Array3d *Array3d_Dup (Array3d *pObjDest, Array3d *pObjSrc)
{
    if (pObjSrc && pObjDest && pObjSrc->elSize == pObjDest->elSize && pObjSrc->side == pObjDest->side) {
        int     iBufferSize = pObjSrc->side * pObjSrc->elSize * pObjSrc->side * pObjSrc->elSize * pObjSrc->side * pObjSrc->elSize;

        memcpy (pObjDest->buffer, pObjSrc->buffer, iBufferSize);
    } else {
        pObjDest = NULL;
    }

    return pObjDest;
}

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Array3d *pObj = Array3d_Factory (10, 20 * sizeof(char));

    char *pChar = pObj->Access (pObj, 1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @csotiriou, you are welcome.  I actually enjoyed playing with the problem.  It was kind of relaxing to do a small thing like this.  So thank you for the opportunity!